# Erro de tamanho de Campo ao executar Insert em PostgreSQL em aplicação Delphi

Tags: delphi, postgresql

Estou com um problema que só poderia estar acontecendo em uma sexta-feira #13.

Tenho uma aplicação em Delphi que controla envios de SEDEX e utilizo o Banco de Dados em PostgreSQL.

Em uma determinada coluna, chamada de *sdx_cepnet*, armazeno a informação que gera o Código de Barras. Esta informação provém de um campo no formulário (um *TMaskEdit* com máscara *00000-000;0;*)

A partir do conteúdo deste campo aplico uma fórmula para adicionar um dígito de verificação e incluo um caractere de controle no início (*start*) e no fim (*stop*) do código de barras.

Ex.: Supondo o CEP **12345-678** o CEPNET será **/123456784\**  - 4 é o DV, / é caractere de start, \ caractere de stop.

Até aqui tudo acontece como manda o figurino, todos os valores chegam correto a instrução SQL.

Só que ao executar a instrução de INSERT ela falha com o erro de valor muito longo para o campo char(11) (que já confirmei ser o campos sdx_cepnet, por via das dúvidas).

Segue parte relevante da DDL da tabela

```
CREATE TABLE public.tbsdx (
  sdx_numobj NUMERIC(9,0),
  sdx_siglaobj CHAR(2),
  sdx_paisorigem CHAR(2),
  sdx_cep CHAR(8),
  sdx_numobj2 VARCHAR(13),
  sdx_cepnet CHAR(11), -- << CAMPO EM QUESTÃO
-- (...)
) WITH (oids = true);
```

Código da Unit

```
  // (...) Outros códigos

  // Início Calculo DV CEP
  v_soma := 0;
  for i:= 1 to Length(MkEdCep.Text) do
    v_soma := v_soma + StrToInt(copy(MkEdCep.Text, i, 1));

  v_soma := v_soma Mod 10;
  if v_soma > 0 then
      v_soma := 10 - v_soma;

  CEPr := Format('/%s%d\', [MkEdCep.Text, v_soma]);
  v_soma := Length(CEPr); // DEBUG
  // Fim Calculo DV CEP

  with dm do
    begin
      SqlAux1.Close;
      SqlAux1.SQL.Clear;
      SqlAux1.SQL.Add('UPDATE tbsdx ');
      SqlAux1.SQL.Add('SET sdx_cepnet = :cepnet, sdx_valor = :valor, ');
      // (...) Outros campos
      SqlAux1.SQL.Add('WHERE sdx_numobj2 = :numboj2 ');
      SqlAux1.ParamByName('cepnet').AsString := CEPr;
      SqlAux1.ParamByName('valor').AsFloat := Moeda2Float(EdValor.Text);
      SqlAux1.ParamByName('numboj2').AsString := EdObjeto.Text;
      try
        SqlAux1.ExecSQL; // Executando a instrução
        if SqlAux1.RowsAffected > 0 then
     // ...continua
```

Segue o DEBUG e o erro

[image: Conteúdo da Variável CEPr contendo o CEPNET]

[image: Informação de Tamanho da String]

[image: Mensagem de Erro de Execução de Instrução]

O que já tentei que não deu certo

- Colocar *'/123456784\' diretamente na variável CEPr
- Usar Trim
- Usar copy(string, 1, 11)

O que faz a instrução executar corretamente

- Usar copy(string, 1, 10)
- Usar '12345678940'

*A pergunta é:* **Como fazer o campo aceitar o valor correto??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após um bom tempo de testes e pesquisa descobri porque acontecia o problema.

Eu acreditei cegamente que utilizar os métodos de *Bind* da lib **ZEOS** era a mesma coisa que em outros objetos de outras linguagens, como Hibernate ou PDO, mas estava completamente errado.

O método **.BindByParam** não escapa caracteres. Apenas substitui o *placeholder* com o conteúdo passado. O mesmo acontece com **.Params[indice]** e como **\** é um caractere especial para o PostgreSQL, ele entendia que eu estava escapando o próximo caractere, fazendo com que o erro acontecesse.

Provavelmente este problema não seja exclusivo do uso de ZEOS com PostgreSQL. Deve acontecer também com Oracle e SQL Server.

A solução foi utilizar o operador de escape do PostgreSQL (**E**) na string base.

```
SqlAux1.SQL.Add('SET sdx_cepnet = E:cepnet, ');
```

o que fará com que o código

```
SqlAux1.ParamByName('cepnet').AsString := '/123456784\';
```

resulte em

```
SqlAux1.SQL.Add('SET sdx_cepnet = E''/123456784\'', '); // '' É a forma do Delphi de escapar aspas em uma string
```

Mais detalhes sobre escape correto de caracteres em PGSQL podem ser encontrados na documentação oficial em http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE

Answer (score 0):

Não recomendo a você usar um campo CHAR para armazenar esse tipo de informação, troque para VARCHAR e faça os testes. Campos CHAR não são bons para lidar com alguns símbolos! Sem falar no desperdício de espaço para armazenar informações!

Aqui você pode encontrar mais informações sobre o assunto: [Tipos para cadeias de caracteres](http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg80/datatype-character.html).

Comment: Entendo a recomendação sobre usar VARCHAR E CHAR, porém internamente no POSTGRESQL não há diferença nesses tipos além da reserva do espaço (explicação inclusa no link que postou) o que leva a a crer que se houver um problema com "alguns símbolos" em CHAR também haverá em VARCHAR. No meu caso, a modelagem não pode ser alterada, embora eu possa fazer testes.

Comment: @MarcosRegis, o VARCHAR aceita qualquer símbolo, já o CHAR não é bem assim! Aguardo os testes!

Comment: Sua resposta está ruim e vou dizer porque. Primeiro, voce menciona **alguns simbolos** mas não diz quais. Segundo, não mostrou a documentação informando que existe diferença na armazenagem de conteudo entre VARCHAR e CHAR mesmo eu tendo dito que não há e que o próprio link que postou não informa. Terceiro, voce supos que daria certo a alteração para VARCHAR sem ter a mínima certeza de que corrigiria o problema. Alterei o campo para VARCHAR e fiz o teste e o erro persistiu. 
Porém nem tudo está perdido, baseado no que disse sobre "simbolos" mudei a abordagem e entendi onde estava o problema.

Comment: Seu comentário está ruim e vou dizer porque. Primeiro, você não leu o link que lhe ofereci para poder dizer sobre a Primeira (Consulte a Seção 4.1.2.1 para obter informações sobre a sintaxe dos literais cadeias de caracteres). Segundo, o próprio link oferecido para mais informações É A DOCUMENTAÇÃO do PostgreSQL 8.0.0. Terceiro, na certeza que você interpreta de forma errada as respostas e efetua um certo ataque a provável única pessoa que lhe tentou ajudar ate agora, me retiro de sua pergunta removendo brevemente minha resposta!

Comment: Embora na frieza das letra pareça ter sido isso, não foi. Eu consegui chegar até a solução **baseado no seu comentário**. Mencionei sobre resposta ruim porque ela não ajuda a possíveis outros desenvolvedores com problemas semelhantes e ainda levanta uma questão sobre diferença de tipos. Eu li a página inteira mesmo sendo para uma versão do PostgreSQL muito antiga na esperança de que encontrasse o que mencionou sobre símbolos. Se alterasse a resposta de forma que houvesse aprendizado sobre o problema eu teria marcado com +1. Perceba que tbm não marquei com -1. E sim, agradeço seu esforço.

Comment: @MarcosRegis, a questão não é ganhar +1 ou -1, observe que não sou colecionador de pontos, eu não apaguei a resposta pois vou deixa-la para que os demais leia e extraia a resposta, claro, nada mastigadinho, mas faça você mesmo amigo, leia o item citado (4.1.2.1) do link que postei, trata-se exatamente do que você formulou como resposta! Sem mais delongas por aqui, afinal, Resposta já foi dada!